# zpl how do i inset de barcode value inside the barcode?

Tags: barcode, zpl

I have a client who wants their barcode to look like this: [image: barcode with inset]
it currently looks like this:

```
^FX^A0N,40,30^BY1^BCN,90,Y,N,N,D
^FD5057913162382^FS
```

[image: regular barcode]

i have tried to change the type of barcode however this makes the barcode unreadable.

```
^A0N,40,30^BY3^B9N,90,Y,N,Y
^FD5057913162382^FS
```

[image: visually correct barcode]

Does anyone have an idea on how to achieve a barcode that looks like (img 1)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first example prints a Code 128 barcode using the ^BC command and your second example prints a UPC-E barcode using the ^B9 command.
The image at the top, however, shows an EAN-13 barcode. This means that you should use the ^BE command.

I tried this on my SATO CLNX printer (running a ZPL emulator)

```
^XA
^FO100,100^BY3
^BEN,100,Y,N
^FD5057913162382^FS
^XZ
```

This is the printout:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJcl3.png)